# React websockets disappear on refresh

Tags: reactjs, websocket, react-hooks, rxjs

So I have a websocket connection that is open and I notice once I refresh the page the websocket messages disappears. I've read online that this is supposed to happen. What is a good way to persist these messages so that they do not disappear. Right now I have the websocket messages in a react state. I've seen some say localstorage or cookies, but I don't think that is scalable as their can be thousands of messages in minutes that could overload the browser storage? Below I am using `react-use-websocket` package and I get the last message and store that inside a state array. That is the wrong approach I need a longer storage solution.

```
const { lastJsonMessage, lastMessage, sendMessage, readyState, getWebSocket } = useWebSocket(resultUrl, {
    //Will attempt to reconnect on all close events, such as server shutting down
    shouldReconnect: () => true,
    reconnectAttempts: 10,
    reconnectInterval: 3000
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const val = lastJsonMessage ? JSON.parse(lastJsonMessage as unknown as string) : {};
    if (val !== null && Object.keys(val).length > 0) {
      setMessageHistory((prev) => prev.concat(val));
    }
  }, [lastJsonMessage, setMessageHistory]);

  // Get Video assets after finishing;
  useEffect(() => {
    messageHistory.forEach((msg) => {
      const { type } = msg;
      if (type === 'video.live_stream.recording' || type === 'video.live_stream.active') {
        const localPlaybackId = msg.data?.playback_ids[0];
        setPlaybackId(localPlaybackId);
      }
      setVideoType(type);
    });
  }, [messageHistory, videoType]);

  const connectionStatus = {
    [ReadyState.CONNECTING]: 'Connecting',
    [ReadyState.OPEN]: 'Open',
    [ReadyState.CLOSING]: 'Closing',
    [ReadyState.CLOSED]: 'Closed',
    [ReadyState.UNINSTANTIATED]: 'Uninstantiated'
  }[readyState];

  if (liveStreamId) {
    sendMessage(liveStreamId);
  }

  messageHistory.filter((msg) => {
    msg.data.id === liveStreamId;
  });
```

Comment: This is a design qustion instead of a "React websockets disappear on refresh" question.

Comment: Yeah I guess its kind of two issues, is the design correct also what to do about websockets disappearing on refreshing, cause i still have that issue as well.

Comment: React won't keep data, since itself does not have a means of storage. Not sure what you gonna do with the "thousands of messages in minutes", as it will provide terrible user experience if you were to dump them to the UI.

Answer (score 0):

in this case, usually when the app is loaded you should do a GET request to the server in order to load all the last messages. Also since you are talking about "thousands of messages" you should implement a lazy loading aka paginator or infinite-scroll